# Issue querying _Click table to get users clicking the same number of times in two or more different `LinkNames`

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, data-views

I am having a hard time with a query that I did for Salesforce Marketing Cloud, and you might know where is the error.
I am querying the table ***_Click***, ([table schema](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_click/)), and I want all my users that had cliked more than three times in a link with the same ***LinkName***I also want to see only the ***LinkName*** with the ***maximum*** number of clicks for each user.
The query works pretty well, if I don't have the same user clicking the same number of times in two or more different ***LinkName***, trying to avoid that I used the data ***EventDate*** and ask for the latest click date, but this is also not working.

Some important information:
   The data retrieve from the table ***_Click*** will be use to populate a table with the follow schema
   
Field name - EmailAddress > DataType - EmailAddress > Length - 254 > PrimaryKey - True
   
Field name - SubscriberID > DataType - Number > Length - not limited > PrimaryKey - False
   
Field name - LinkName > DataType - Text > Length - 100 > PrimaryKey - False
   
Field name - maxClicks > DataType - Number > Length - not limited > PrimaryKey - False
   
Field name - ClickDate > DataType - Date > Length - not limited > PrimaryKey - False

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.SubscriberID,a.maxClicks,a.LinkName,a.SubscriberKey as EmailAddress,a.ClickDate
FROM (SELECT SubscriberID,COUNT(LinkName) as maxClicks,LinkName,SubscriberKey,MAX(EventDate) as ClickDate
FROM _Click
WHERE convert(varchar(24), EventDate, 113) >= convert(varchar(24), getdate()-9, 113)
GROUP BY SubscriberID,SubscriberKey,LinkName) as a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SubscriberID,COUNT(LinkName) as maxClicks,LinkName,SubscriberKey,MAX(EventDate) as ClickDate
FROM _Click
WHERE convert(varchar(24), EventDate, 113) >= convert(varchar(24), getdate()-9, 113)
GROUP BY SubscriberID,SubscriberKey,LinkName) as b
ON a.SubscriberID = b.SubscriberID AND a.maxClicks < b.maxClicks AND a.ClickDate < b.ClickDate
WHERE a.maxClicks > 3
AND convert(varchar(24), a.ClickDate, 113) >= convert(varchar(24), a.ClickDate, 113)
AND a.LinkName in ('Beach','Skiing','Nature','Wellness','Business','Shopping','Food_Culture','Fun')
AND b.maxClicks is NULL AND b.ClickDate IS NULL
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Felipe, this isn't really a Marketing Cloud question, but rather a clusterSQL. Can you describe what the output should look Ike,please? Keen to help while sparing clock-cycles.

Comment: Hey Andrew, the output for this query should be, if the same user did 9 clicks in a 'New York' deal at 25.12.2017 09:35, and also 9 clicks in a 'Las Vegas' deal at 25.12.2017 09:36, I should get him in the table with the following data `SubscriberID = 111111,maxClicks = 9,LinkName = ''Las Vegas, EmailAddress = ''XXX'',ClickDate = 25.12.2017 09:36. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felipe, I'm not entirely certain I understand your requirements, but based on your description, it sounds like you could use the ROW_NUMBER function here to return only one row per subscriber. Something like this...

```
SELECT
  c.SubscriberID,
  c.EmailAddress,
  c.LinkName,
  c.ClickDate,
  c.NumClicks AS MaxClicks
FROM
  (
    SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SubscriberID ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC) AS RowNumber,
      SubscriberID,
      SubscriberKey AS EmailAddress,
      LinkName,
      MAX(EventDate) AS ClickDate,
      COUNT(1) AS NumClicks
    FROM
      _Click WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
      EventDate >= GETDATE() - 9 AND
      LinkName IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      SubscriberID,
      SubscriberKey,
      LinkName
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 3
  ) AS c
WHERE
  c.RowNumber = 1
```

If you need one row per subscriber/linkname combination, then Partition by those two fields, rather than SubscriberID alone.

Comment: Good. Please mark as answered if that's sorted for you, now.